# Can I make IIS add (inject) HTML to every page it serves?

Tags: iis, iis-6

I would like to add some HTML to every page that our IIS 6 server serves.  It's serving static HTML for the most part.  Is this something IIS or an extension can do?  I would need some control over how and where the HTML is injected, in this case before the  tag.  Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Natively I believe the only thing you can do is insert a document footer (on the Documents tab).

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with ASP.NET, you could write a **HTTP Response Filter** to do that.

Read this [article by Milan Negovan](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters.aspx).

The **HttpResponse** class has a very useful property:

```
public Stream Filter {get; set;}
```

> MSDN provides a helpful description of
>   this property: "Gets or sets a
>   wrapping filter object used to modify
>   the HTTP entity body before
>   transmission." Confused? In other
>   words, you can assign your own custom
>   filter to each page response.
>   HttpResponse will send all content
>   through your filter. This filter will
>   be invoked right before the response
>   goes back to the user and you will
>   have a change to transform it if need
>   be.
>
> This could be extremely helpful if you
>   need to transform output from "legacy"
>   code or substitute placeholders
>   (header, footer, navigation, you name
>   it) with proper code. Besides, at
>   times it's simply impossible to ensure
>   that every server control plays by the
>   rules and produces what you expect it
>   to. Enter response filters.
>
> The Filter property is of type
>   `System.IO.Stream`. To create your own
>   filter you need to derive a class from
>   System.IO.Stream (which is an abstract
>   class) and add implementation to its
>   numerous methods.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to inject some CSS before the  using the URL Rewrite Module, via an outbound rule:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
            <rule name="Add custom CSS" preCondition="IsHTML">
                <match filterByTags="None" pattern="&lt;/head>" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;/path/to/custom/styles_override.css&quot;>&lt;/head>" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="IsHTML">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

You should be able to do the same with html content, instead of css...

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It solved part of my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66145716/the-rewrite-provider-error-in-an-outbound-rewrite-rule?noredirect=1#comment116948614_66145716

Answer (score 1):

In IIS proper, you can add a footer, which is great for a copyright line, or similar. If you want more control, to truly "inject", I would create an HTTP Handler (.NET) that handles .html requests and adds what you need.

If you are "old school", use ISAPI filters instead. Too much work for my tastes.