# Is it possible to inject html footer from IIS for all site?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a iis 8 server running in windows server 2012. Currently 3 different websites are running on it and the other two will be integrated shortly. All 5 websites are being managed from their respective owner. I want to append 'hosted at xxxx' at the bottom of all pages that is being served by this iis. I can do it application wise is global.asax, but is it possible to do that at iis level, so that I donot edit the hosted application? All websites are in .net 4 and form based.

Comment: What have you tried? See [Can I make IIS add (inject) HTML to every page it serves?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638866/can-i-make-iis-add-inject-html-to-every-page-it-serves).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can write an [IIS Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-a-module-using-net) that will inject HTML into the HTTP Response Stream.  You can add this Module to each application individually by dropping the DLL into the app's BIN folder and registering it in the Web.Config.  Alternatively you could create a [Strong-Named Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwb8f617%28VS.80%29.aspx) and register it with IIS for all sites.

Comment: thanks, i was looking for this only, since modules will be on iis and I can be sure that their application is not edited by me. Also it is easier than other methods.