# The rewrite provider error in an outbound rewrite rule

Tags: iis

I am supporting a website with many .html files. The site runs in IIS 10 on Windows 2016. Now I am asked to insert the following Google Tag Manager code immediately after `<head>`.

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'xyz.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'xyz.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/xyz.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','xyz-ABCDEFG');</script>
```

Obviously, inserting this piece of code manually into each html file is a bad idea in many aspects. I am trying to use outbound rules for the job. Basically, the idea is to replace `<head>` in the response with `<head>` and the above code. I entered it through the Edit Outbound Rule interface in  IIS and the following is what I got in web.config after saving it:

```
 <rule name="GTM head" preCondition="IsHTML">
    <match filterByTags="None" pattern="&lt;head>" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="&lt;head>&lt;script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'xyz.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'xyz.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&amp;l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/xyz.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','xyz-ABCDEFG');&lt;/script>" />
</rule>
```

However, I saw this error message in IIS when saving it in the Edit Outbound Rule interface.

```
The rewrite provider "w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'xyz.start'" does not exist.
```

If I load a HTML page, the browser displays this error:

```
HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

Any help or input is really appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

Before this post, I looked at and tried this piece (there is no example for my situation)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Tag_Filters

I also read and tried this piece

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Tag_Filters

I wasn't able to get it work. Basically, no clue how to make it work.

**UPDATE 2**

I was also asked to insert this piece of code immediately after `<body>` tag, and I was able to use an outbound rule successfully.

```
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=xyz-ABCDEFG"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>


<rule name="GTM body" preCondition="IsHTML">
    <match filterByTags="None" pattern="&lt;body(\s*[^>]*)>" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="&lt;body{R:1}>&lt;noscript>&lt;iframe src=&quot;https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-WR7TNHP&quot; height=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;0&quot; style=&quot;display:none;visibility:hidden&quot;>&lt;/iframe>&lt;/noscript>" />
</rule>
```

Comment: You can try to add the rewrite provider in the url rewrite. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module).

Comment: Thanks for your input! I saw that page before my post. The difficult thing to me is that it has no example for my situation (replace, not redirect). I have no clue about how to do it. Tried many things. None worked.

Comment: Have you tried to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85) to get more information?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I never tried failed request tracking before. If I load a HTML page, I see this error: `HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error. The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred`. Do you think failed request tracking would help in my case in which IIS already indicates the error with the outbound rewrite rule in the first place and page loading further confirms it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did more reading and found this article:

https://blogs.iis.net/danielvl/how-to-escape-curly-brackets-in-url-rewrite-rule

Basically, the solution is replace opening `{` with this function:

```
{UrlDecode:%7B}
```

Hope this would help somebody in the future.